# How to access /usr/bin/ from snap?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, snapcraft

I am developing a snap in Go but I have a problem when I try to run this command:

```
args := []string{"journalctl", "-n 200", "--no-pager"}
    output, err := RunCMD("sudo", args, true)
```

If I run it on the Ubuntu Core machine terminal it works. The problem is that by running the following command from the terminal I see the journalctl version in **/usr/bin/journalctl** while from snap I see **/bin/journalctl** version.

Do I need to enable any permissions on snapcraft.yaml to access this service?